# Cannot create scheduled-query via az cli - how does the condition parse?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cli, azure-monitoring

I'm trying to set a log query alert through the az cli but I cannot for the life of me get the `--condition` option to accept a query with a quote in it.

E.g.:

```
az monitor scheduled-query create -n "Log Alert" -g rg --scopes /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/components/ai --condition "count 'customEvents | where name == "Event" ' > 360" --description "Check something"
```

But I just get this error:

```
cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror : BadRequestError: BadRequest: {
  "error": {
    "message": "The request had some invalid properties",
    "code": "BadArgumentError",
    "correlationId": "xxxx",
    "innererror": {
      "code": "SemanticError",
      "message": "A semantic error occurred.",
      "innererror": {
        "code": "SEM0100",
        "message": "'where' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'Event'"
      }
    }
  }
}
BadRequestError: BadRequest: {
  "error": {
    "message": "The request had some invalid properties",
    "code": "BadArgumentError",
    "correlationId": "xxxx",
    "innererror": {
      "code": "SemanticError",
      "message": "A semantic error occurred.",
      "innererror": {
        "code": "SEM0100",
        "message": "'where' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'Event'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm copying the example on the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/scheduled-query/monitor/scheduled-query?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_scheduled_query_az_monitor_scheduled_query_create but I can't find the right combination of quote marks or escape characters to get this to parse, I've tried from a windows powershell and a bash cloud shell but that makes no difference.

Comment: if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

**This is because you probably don't have Events table in `Schema` that can be checked under 'Logs' tile of your Log Analytics workspace:**

[image]

**Further**, check if you have followed [Collect Windows event log data sources with Log Analytics agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-windows-events) to setup logs.

*Check out [GitHub issue#38928](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/38928) around same issue.*

#### Edit:

---

I reached out to the PG and got to know that this is a known issue and it will be fixed in [this](http://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/pull/2904/files) PR. Pls note that it's in review stage and will be released soon.

Comment: I'm not sure that makes much difference here, the table I'm searching on is customEvents and the column is name, I can run my query ok in the portal, I can also make the alert ok using the portal UI, just not the az cli command. https://imgur.com/a/fgDIddp

Comment: Are you running command on right subscription?

Comment: You should have Event table as well. Your error message says : "'where' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'Event'"

Comment: "Event" is the search term, I'm looking in the customEvents table of application insights, if I change the condition to look like this I still get the same error  `--condition "count 'customEvents | search "Event" ' > 360"`

Comment: Are you running `--condition "count 'customEvents | search "Event" ' > 360"` command in your Portal UI? Because the screenshot you shared has some other query which does not have `Event` in it.

Comment: I'm running `customEvents | search "Event" ` in the portal UI - wrapping it in a count errors - but event is the search term, not a table - this is application insights I'm searching if that helps.

Comment: Ok, let me circle back to the product group and let you know a solution.

Comment: Good News: I reached out to the PG and got to know that this is a known issue and it will be fixed in this PR: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/pull/2904/files. Pls note that it's in review stage and will be released soon.

Comment: If this answer helps, could you accept it as an answer to help the community?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the new feature of creating scheduled query via cli is not available. I found [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/pull/10238#issuecomment-586685397) that mentions this code is not merged into master branch.

To escape double quotes for `"Event"`, you can modify it as `\"Event\"`. And then run the command, you will get an error message which provides the usage of `--condition`. But I tried many ways as per this tips, no good luck. Regards the issue mentioned above, I though it's currently impossible to create it via azure cli.

[image]

If azure cli is not a must, you can try use azure powershell [New-AzScheduledQueryRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/new-azscheduledqueryrule?view=azps-5.4.0) cmdlet.